# Rust compile error on macOS related to GMP

Tags: macos, rust, gmp

Something like

```
use super::gmp::mpz::Mpz;
...
pub type MyMPZ = Mpz;

...

fn a() -> Option<MyMPZ>;
```

It (along with many other Rust files, libs and other dependencies) compiles and runs OK on Ubuntu and even Windows, but on macOS Mojave
I get

> expected struct `gmp::mpz::Mpz`, found enum `std::option::Option`
>
> note: expected type `&gmp::mpz::Mpz`
>   
>                                                       found type `&std::option::Option`

I installed GMP with Brew, but I tried with GMP 6.1.2 built by myself with the same results.

**Update 1:** 
Seems MCVE doesn't make much sense since I have two exact copies of project in same root like root\example1 and root\example2. One copy builds ok, another gives the error message. Tried cargo clean etc numerous times to same effect.

**Update 2:** 
Seems it's definitely some sort of caching issue. Because when I build dependencies, they take custom built 32bit version of gmp.lib from `C:\Users\<userName>\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-i686-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-msvc\lib`. So if I checkout dependency and build it separately - tests run there. If I build the whole project, and using my own build dependency crates as .lib I at some point was getting

> expected struct `gmp::mpz::Mpz`, found another struct `gmp::mpz::Mpz`

that seems like mixing of GMP 32/64 bit libraries to me.

Comment: How about `MacPorts` version (`gmp @6.1.2_1 (devel, math)`)?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: For example, is the type alias important for the problem? You've shown methods taking `self` but not the structs they are defined on. If he structs are important, include them. If not, remove them and use functions. Is it important to have two methods? Why do the methods have no bodies? That's not valid Rust. What version of the gmp crate are you using? What version of Rust?

Comment: @Shepmaster The funniest thing - that while I was trying to do MCVE on Windows, I got the very same error. Like on MacOSX - and on Windows now I have two exact copies(if to believe git) of project. In one there is error `expected struct "gmp::mpz::Mpz", found enum "std::option::Option"`- other builds ok!?

Comment: @l'L'l tried MacPorts version - same error:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was cargo dependency hell:) - after multiple unsuccessful reinstalls, cleaning etc I finally was able to rebuild by manually downloading and rebuilding and re-referencing local paths of dependencies that were referenced with git. From then on - all was building fine no matter if I referenced locally or via git or crates.